# Unable to run OpenCV Program in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, opencv, installation

I was trying to run a opencv code with the following lines

```
import cv2 as cv

image = cv.imread('Photos\cat.jpg')

cv.imshow('Image of Catt', image)

cv.waitKey(0)
```

and when I run the code in Visual Studio Code I get the error in the output tab of the bottom of the screen after clicking on the run code button on the top right part of the screen

```
[Running] python -u 
"c:\Users\jimmy\Documents\Projects\Programing\Python\Learning 
Python\Youtube\openCV\read.py"
[ WARN:0@0.131] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-                
python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp (239) 
cv::findDecoder imread_('Photos\cat.jpg'): can't open/read file: 
check file path/integrity
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\jimmy\Documents\Projects\Programing\Python\Learning 
Python\Youtube\openCV\read.py", line 5, in <module>
    cv.imshow('Image of Catt', image)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv- 
python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: 
(-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'


[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.243 seconds
```

So What I did was reinstall opencv with many methods

I did that by uninstalling using many methods such as

```
pip uninstall opencv
```

I get the error

```
WARNING: Skipping opencv as it is not installed.
```

I tried

```
pip3 uninstall opencv
```

Which I get the error

```
WARNING: Skipping opencv as it is not installed
```

I tried

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
```

which I succeeded uninstalling opencv with the output of

```
Found existing installation: opencv-python 4.5.5.64
Uninstalling opencv-python-4.5.5.64:
  Would remove:
    c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cv2\*
c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\opencv_python- 
4.5.5.64.dist-info\*
Proceed (Y/n)? Y
  Successfully uninstalled opencv-python-4.5.5.64
```

But just in case I have other installations of python I uninstalled with

```
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python
```

which I got

```
Found existing installation: opencv-contrib-python 4.5.5.64
Uninstalling opencv-contrib-python-4.5.5.64:
  Would remove:
    c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\opencv_contrib_python-4.5.5.64.dist-info\*
Proceed (Y/n)? Y
  Successfully uninstalled opencv-contrib-python-4.5.5.64
```

I also uninstalled with

```
pip3 uninstall opencv-python
```

which I got

```
WARNING: Skipping opencv-python as it is not installed.
```

I tried

```
pip3 uninstall opencv-contrib-python
```

which I got

```
WARNING: Skipping opencv-contrib-python as it is not installed.
```

but at this point I was very sure that I have uninstalled opencv

I now installed opencv with

```
pip install opencv
```

Which I got

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv
```

I tried again installing opencv with

```
pip3 install opencv
```

Which again I got

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv
```

I tried again with

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Which I got

```
  Using cached opencv_python-4.5.5.64-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl (35.4 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.22.3)
Installing collected packages: opencv-python
Successfully installed opencv-python-4.5.5.64
```

I wanna make sure it was on python3 so I installed with

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

Which I then got

```
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (4.5.5.64)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.22.3)
```

But I wasn't completely satisfied yet so I installed again with

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Which I got

```
    Collecting opencv-contrib-python
  Using cached opencv_contrib_python-4.5.5.64-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl (42.2 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from opencv-contrib-python) (1.22.3)
Installing collected packages: opencv-contrib-python
Successfully installed opencv-contrib-python-4.5.5.64
```

I also installed with pip3

```
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python
```

Which I got

```
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-contrib-python in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (4.5.5.64)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from opencv-contrib-python) (1.22.3)
```

I heard people also installing with other methods so just in case of some error I tried these

python -m pip install opencv

Which gave me

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv
```

I tried

```
python3 -m pip install opencv
```

Which I got the exaact same results

I then tried

```
pip install -I opencv-python
```

Which I got

```
Collecting opencv-python
  Using cached opencv_python-4.5.5.64-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl (35.4 MB)
Collecting numpy>=1.14.5
  Using cached numpy-1.22.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (14.7 MB)
Installing collected packages: numpy, opencv-python
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
```

daal4py 2021.3.0 requires daal==2021.2.3, which is not installed.
numba 0.54.1 requires numpy<1.21,>=1.17, but you have numpy 1.22.3 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed numpy-1.22.3 opencv-python-4.5.5.64

At this point I was finally satisfied

So I ran my code with the start button in Visual Studio Code on the top right corner

```
import cv2 as cv

image = cv.imread('Photos\cat.jpg')

cv.imshow('Image of Catt', image)

cv.waitKey(0)
```

In the output section it wrote

```
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\jimmy\Documents\Projects\Programing\Python\Learning Python\Youtube\openCV\read.py"
[ WARN:0@0.605] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp (239) cv::findDecoder imread_('Photos\cat.jpg'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\jimmy\Documents\Projects\Programing\Python\Learning Python\Youtube\openCV\read.py", line 5, in <module>
    cv.imshow('Image of Catt', image)
```

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

```
[Done] exited with code=1 in 1.233 seconds
```

I used all the methods but it still doesn't work, any help is appreciated!
btw I am on windows and if you are too tired reading this much I am just afraid I didn't clarify on something or didn't try out a obvious answer.

Comment: first learn how to format code and messages in question - to make it more readable.

Comment: you have to install `opencv-python`, not `opencv`

Comment: you may have very common problem - you have two Pythons installed and you installed module in one Python but you run code in other Python. But Pythons don't share modules. Every Python has own `pip` - ie. `pip3`, `pip3.7`, `pip3.8`, etc. OR try `python -m pip install ...`

Comment: this has nothing to do with the install of opencv. you can delete 90% of your post. error messages mean something. **the image path in your code** is wrong. please learn about the meaning of backslashes in python strings. either escape them or use "r-strings".

Answer (score 0):

The command for installing opencv for python is:
`python3 -m pip install opencv-python`. This command assumes you are installing opencv for python3. You may also run just `python -m pip install opencv-python` or `pip install opencv-python`. Visit https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/ to learn more about opencv-python, the different versions available and how to install them.

Comment: Doesn't work sadly,
for the first command which is 
python3 -m pip install opencv-python
I got the error
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in c:\users\jimmy\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (4.5.5.64)                                             Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.5 in c:\users\jimmy\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.22.3)

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will work !

```
pip install -I opencv-python
pip install --ignore-installed opencv-python
```

[Referance](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/de5/tutorial_py_setup_in_windows.html)

Answer (score 0):

I also have stumbled across this issue.
The problem seems to be related to the specific **opencv-python** version 4.5.5.64.
Run the command:

```
pip install -U opencv-python==4.5.5.62
```

and you should be able to run your code. At least it solved it in my case.
you can find many occurances of similar behaviours across multiple opencv distribution in a lot of open github issues, like the following one:
[Opencv Github Issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/362)

The code I used to test the issue is the one that follows:

```
import cv2

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fps = video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
print(f"Frames per second using video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) : {fps}")

while True:
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    if ret:
        cv2.imshow('temp', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
```